# PL/SQL - Pre actions if cursor is found

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a simple cursor like this:

```
CURSOR emp_cur
IS
  SELECT *
    FROM employee
    WHERE age > 20;
```

In my procedure, I want to do some pre-actions only if there are employee in cursor. After that pre-action, I process all rows.

I need this because only if exists employee in that cursor i need to cleanup some tables, otherwise i should "RETURN".

so the code could be:

```
OPEN emp_cur;
/* Here i need to do pre-action only if emp_cur has rows*/
IF /* has rows*/
THEN
  /* do some actions*/
END IF;

LOOP
  FETCH emp_cur INTO emp_rec;
  EXIT WHEN emp_cur%NOTFOUND;
END LOOP;

CLOSE emp_cur;
```

For now, i have a "dirty" solution where i open cursor:

1. First to check if there are rows
2. Do pre-action and close
3. Open/fetch again to process rows, and close again

Comment: If you've solved your problem, you should post it as an answer, rather than editing the question.

Comment: Sorry, i've deleted the UPDATE and wrote answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thinking a little i've wrote this procedure that avoid an IF inside the loop. I know, is a little "strange" but is the only thing i've think works:

```
OPEN emp_cur;
FECTH emp_cur INTO emp_rec;

IF emp_cur%FOUND
THEN
  -- pre actions
END IF;

LOOP
  EXIT WHEN emp_cur%NOTFOUND;
  -- do something in the loop
  FECTH emp_cur INTO emp_rec; -- First fetch was done before the if
END LOOP;

CLOSE emp_cur;
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `emp_cur` instead of `import_lav_cur` ?

Comment: You are right! Was cut&past from my real code, sorry :)

Answer (score 4):

> First to check if there are rows

You cannot know about the rows until you **FETCH**.

From documentation [link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/sqloperations.htm#CJAEDJEE) ,

> After a cursor or cursor variable is opened but before the first
>   fetch, %FOUND returns NULL. After any fetches, it returns TRUE if the
>   last fetch returned a row, or FALSE if the last fetch did not return a
>   row.

Once you have fetched the rows, then before processing the rows, you could use **%FOUND**.

For example,

```
OPEN c1;
  LOOP
    FETCH c1 INTO my_ename, my_salary;
    IF c1%FOUND THEN  -- fetch succeeded
      -- Do something
    ELSE  -- fetch failed, so exit loop
      EXIT;
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
```

Comment: in this way, i dont do "do something" for every execution (FETCH)? I need to do pre-action only once and, after that... loop on every rows. In my case, pre-action is a DELETE and the LOOP need to insert "fresh" rows.

Comment: @Mistre83, if you want to do some special action before the first row, you can put an extra IF clause inside the `IF c1%FOUND THEN`, something like `IF v_firstrow = TRUE THEN -- Do DELETE ... v_firstrow=FALSE; END IF;` and after this ... `-- Do something`

Comment: @ruudvan yes this wat i have think to do.... i dont like it so much but if there are other ways, i will do this :)

Comment: @Mistre83, Well, since you have already fetched, you could certainly "do something", isn't it? Here the context of "do something" implies that you could make some transaction, since the previous statement of PL/SQL returns a boolean as **TRUE**. Therefore, you are legitimate to take some action. Good luck!